# zend framework layouts

Tags: zend-framework, layout

According to [Rob Allen's tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/simple-zend_layout-example/)  :  to use a layout into my zend application I should put:

```
$response = $this->getResponse();
$response->insert('header', $this->view->render('header.phtml')); 
$response->insert('sidebar', $this->view->render('sidebar.phtml')); 
$response->insert('footer', $this->view->render('footer.phtml'));
```

into the init() function of the IndexController, to generate the header,footer and the sidebar for every action.
I would like to use the same layout for all my views, should I put this portion of code into all the controllers??? (I'm using ZF 1.11)

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize a zend layout by doing the following in your bootstrap:

```
Zend_Layout::startMvc();
```

and you can also specify where your keeping your layouts

```
$layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
$layout->setLayoutPath(__PATH_TO_LAYOUT_FOLDER_);
```

Once that's in place it will be much more efficient than rendering the same view in all your controllers.

Answer (score 1):

The blogpost you are referring to is almost 5 years old and in no way represents the current state of ZF 1.11, you should use the [official Zend_Layout documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.layout.html) or [Robs ZF1 tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/)

Comment: OK thanks you for the links, I didn't know there is a tutorial for the the new versions.

Answer (score 0):

You want a layout default. You can make it calling in the template layout. The Zend Framework Documentation show it better:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.layout.quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

it's even easier then so far presented. In your `application.ini` add this line

`resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"` and the default layout at this path would be named `layout.phtml`.

If you want to change the path or the default layout you may need two lines in your `application.ini`

```
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts"
resources.layout.layout = master
```

in this case the default layout would be `master.phtml`.

to change from the default layout to an alternate is as simple as adding:

```
public function preDispatch() {

        $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('admin');
    }
```

to the controller that needs a new layout, logic can be added so the alternate layout will only be applied to certain actions.